# OpenGL does not update the drawview

Tags: c++, opengl

I have the following drawScene function which draws a sphere. The coords of X,Y are being updated all the time. As far as I can see from the printf the values changed for sure.

The problem is that the sphere does not change position according to the coords but is always drawn at the same place...

```
void drawScene(void){



        //Clear information from last draw
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //Switch to the drawing perspective
glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the drawing perspective

glColor3d(1,0,0);

//glPushMatrix();///

glTranslated(X,Y,-7);//xyz//(X%5)-2.5,Y%5//(((X%6)-3),0,-7)
printf("\n\n\nCOORDS(X)%d  (Y):%d\n\n\n\n",X,Y);
glutSolidSphere(0.3, 25, 20);//3,20,20

//glPopMatrix();///

glutSwapBuffers(); //Send the 3D scene to the screen
        }
```

PS. I am not sure if this is right but every time I want my openGL window to be updated I call the drawScene() or else it is drawn only once.

Comment: Can you show us the call site of this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either call glutPostRedisplay() when you update the X and Y or enable the idleFunc like this:

```
void idle()
{
   glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

and add this in your main:

```
glutIdleFunc(idle);
```